# How to imort a file from a ZIP package in AMPscript code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I had uploaded a .zip package to Portfolio that includes some resoures, e.g. jquery, css etc.. 
And now I`d like to load them in  tag, how should I to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you upload the unzipped files into portfolio, you can then click the properties for any file and get the URL for it. Once you have the URL, you can link to it on a landing page just like any other webpage using HTML.

Comment: Yes, this is ok. But I`d like to do it like in force.com, currently I am just reference them by upload unzipped file.